# A stick length 1 is broken into 2 pieces. Let $Z_1$ be the length of the shorter part. Find $EZ_1$

Tags: probability, random-variables

This is used: If $p(x)$ is continuous, then $P\{x \leq X \leq x+ \Delta x \}= p(x)\Delta x+ o(\Delta x), \Delta x\to 0.$

Let $H_1$ be the occurrence that the point at which the stick is broken is in the first part of the stick (1/2) and $H_2$ the second part respectively. Then we have:

$P\{t < Z_1< t+h\}=P\{t<Z_1<t+h| H_1\}P\{H_1\}+P\{t<Z_1<t+h| H_2\}P\{H_2\}= 2h {1\over 2}+ 2h {1\over 2}= 2h$- I do not understand how this is , I believe it should be just $h$.
Because t+h-t =h ? What am I not seeing >?

Comment: If you're told that the shorter part has length in $(t, t+h)$ (where $0\le t \le t+h\le 1/2$), then there are two intervals where the break could have occurred: one interval of length $h$ that is a distance $t$ from the left end of the stick, and one that's a distance $t$ from the right end of the stick.  The total length of those intervals is $2h$, so that's the probability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative solution. Obviously $Z_1\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$. For any $t\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$,
$$ \mathbb{P}[Z_1\leq t]=2t, $$
hence $Z_1$ is uniformly distributed over $\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$, so that $\mathbb{E}[Z_1]=\frac{1}{4}$ and:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{Z_1}{1-Z_1}\right]=\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{2x}{1-x}\,dx = \color{red}{-1+\log 4}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The distribution function of $Z1 | H1$ is given by $2*\mathbb{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}(x)$, otherwise it's not a density. That's where the 2 is coming from.